# How does official Postgres image create user and database with env variables?

Tags: postgresql, docker

Official Postgres images for Docker uses two environment variables:
POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD to parametrize database creation:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

I expected that the environment variables will be used in the image source:

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bfca9b8a92a99ccfc8f04933b7ecc29a108c7f49/9.4/Dockerfile

but there's not trace of them there.

Could you explain how it is made that a user specified with the environment variables is created with a container?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bfca9b8a92a99ccfc8f04933b7ecc29a108c7f49/9.4/docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: Which is called from the Dockerfile here: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bfca9b8a92a99ccfc8f04933b7ecc29a108c7f49/9.4/Dockerfile#L47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` are used in the [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bfca9b8a92a99ccfc8f04933b7ecc29a108c7f49/9.4/Dockerfile#L47) file [visible here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/bfca9b8a92a99ccfc8f04933b7ecc29a108c7f49/9.4/docker-entrypoint.sh#L40-L58).